# Монетизация программ на C++ и Visual Studio Express

Tags: visual-studio, c++

Доброго времени суток, уважаемые! У меня возник вопрос: могу ли я монетизировать приложения (т. е. продажа права пользования и распространение программы) созданные в Visual Studio C++ Express?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, можете. За комментариями см [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624589/visual-studio-express-2010-license)

Comment: Спасибо, а какие есть ограничения?

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, то основное ограничение - это запрет на распространение Debug-сборки.

Comment: Спасибо огромное.